# arithmetic vector operations in Java

Tags: java, vector, arithmetic-expressions

I have four vectors have same dimension (1 dimensional) and same size. My vectors are consturcated as:

```
Vector<Integer> v1=new Vector<Integer>(5);
Vector<Integer> v2=new Vector<Integer>(5);
Vector<Integer> vp=new Vector<Integer>(5);
Vector<Integer> vs=new Vector<Integer>(5);
```

for example: vp=v1*v2

```
<1 3 4 1 2>
<0 0 2 2 3>
<0 0 8 2 6>
```

and vector subtraction also for example vs=1-v1

```
1-v1= <0 -2 -3 0 -1>
```

is there any function in java to assign the result of multiplication of vectors to vector "vp" and "vs"?

Comment: Yes that would be a start if you want people to start answering YOUR questions.

Comment: You are looking for a math library in Java. Nothing that couldn't be searched within a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no API methods provided for this.

It looks like the definiton might change from one to one , we have implement mannually for this.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [vecmath](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/j3dapi/javax/vecmath/package-summary.html) for vector operations. It is very precise. No rounding errors!